# Solving Duplicated in Access

Tags: database, ms-access

i had a table depends on more than one tables and i get this final 
[ScrrenShoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJmWH.png) have a look in picture

i need to choose from values if firstdate duplicated in specific criteria

for ex . i need one row for 18.2.2016 / max value ( get the greater one ) / min value (get the less one )

Comment: Is the screenshot a query or a table? Are you trying to get rid of the duplicates or only show duplicates? You did not provide enough information to help you. Please provide the structure of the tables involved, and a clearer question about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: the screenshoot for the table i need to make query on this table to get the result i edited in question

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide us with better information, but here is what I think you're looking for.

You need a separate query for each min/max value you want to find. Where you see "MyTable" you need to replace it with the object name shown in the screenshot.

Query 1 "Max"

```
SELECT MyTable.FirstOfDate, Max(MyTable.MaxValue) AS MaxOfMaxValue
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY MyTable.FirstOfDate;
```

Query 2 "Min"

```
SELECT MyTable.FirstOfDate, Min(MyTable.MinValue) AS MinOfMinValue
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY MyTable.FirstOfDate;
```

Query 3 "Merge"

```
SELECT DISTINCT MyTable.FirstOfDate, Max.MaxOfMaxValue, Min.MinOfMinValue
FROM (MyTable 
  INNER JOIN [Max] ON MyTable.FirstOfDate = Max.FirstOfDate) 
INNER JOIN [Min] ON MyTable.FirstOfDate = Min.FirstOfDate
GROUP BY MyTable.FirstOfDate, Max.MaxOfMaxValue, Min.MinOfMinValue;
```